# Excel hyperlinks only work sporadically

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-office

I have a workbook with a fair number of hyperlinks in it, but the hyperlinks only work sporadically. Sometimes a link won't work, I navigate to another sheet, try a different link, go back to the first one and it suddenly works. Sometimes it works three times and stops working on the fourth. Other times I open up the workbook and the link doesn't work from the get-go.

If anyone has had this problem and knows a way to fix it I'd appreciate the insight.

Comment: Are the links used are part of some formula?

Comment: Could you show an example of one that works intermittently.  How were these links created, and how are they being navigated-to?

Comment: All of them only work intermittently. One example is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guided-learning/
The links were created by right clicking, selecting Hyperlink, and pasting the link as the source.

Comment: Should have clarified that I'm receiving an "unexpected error message", it's not just that the link shows up as static text.

Comment: Okay, to expand on that, the links *seem* to work consistently if I already have an internet explorer window open.